# MySQL stored procedure works from command line but phpMyAdmin shows no result. Why?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

*Lots of code below to reproduce the issue.*

I have a stored procedure that works from the command line but when I run it in phpMyAdmin it says "empty result set". I get the same result in phpMyAdmin if I "execute" the procedure in the Routines tab or if I run it in the SQL window (and both with and without variables to set the parameters or hard code them.)

**running the stored procedure from command line:**

```
mysql> call nearest_city_temp(32.63768889, -93.98388889);
+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
| name         | admin1 | country | distance           |
+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
| Mooringsport | LA     | US      | 3.6912517830508866 |
+--------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
1 row in set (2.05 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (2.05 sec)
```

**running the stored procedure from phpMyAdmin**
[image: running a stored procedure in phpMyAdmin]

**the code**

```
CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `geonameid` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `asciiname` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `alternatenames` varchar(4000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(10,7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fclass` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fcode` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(2) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cc2` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin1` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin2` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin3` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin4` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `population` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `elevation` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `gtopo30` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `moddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` point NOT NULL,
  `distance` decimal(12,8)
) ;


INSERT IGNORE INTO `temp` (`geonameid`, `name`, `asciiname`, `alternatenames`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `fclass`, `fcode`, `country`, `cc2`, `admin1`, `admin2`, `admin3`, `admin4`, `population`, `elevation`, `gtopo30`, `timezone`, `moddate`, `position`, `distance`) VALUES
(4341513, 'Shreveport', 'Shreveport', 'SHV,Shreve Town,Shreveport,Shreves Landing,Shrivport,shen li fu bo te,shryfbwrt,shrywpwrt  lwyyzyana,shuribupoto,srivaporta,srybpwrt,syulibeupoteu,Шревепорт,Шривпорт,שריבפורט,شريفبورت,شریوپورت، لوئیزیانا,شریوپورٹ، لوزیانا,श्रीवपोर्ट,シュリーブポート,什里夫波特,슈리브포트', '32.5251500', '-93.7501800', 'P', 'PPLA2', 'US', '', 'LA', '017', '', '', 197204, 44, 50, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe610000001010000004087f9f2027057c048bf7d1d38434040, NULL),
(4317201, 'Blanchard', 'Blanchard', '', '32.5809800', '-93.8926800', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'LA', '017', '', '', 2935, 68, 71, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe61000000101000000c5724bab217957c0a6d0798d5d4a4040, NULL),
(4335921, 'Oil City', 'Oil City', '', '32.7440300', '-93.9715700', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'LA', '017', '', '', 997, 62, 62, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe6100000010100000095f1ef332e7e57c0179f02603c5f4040, NULL),
(4316471, 'Benton', 'Benton', 'Benton,Бентон', '32.6948700', '-93.7418500', 'P', 'PPLA2', 'US', '', 'LA', '015', '', '', 2015, 63, 66, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe6100000010100000068226c787a6f57c05b7c0a80f1584040, NULL),
(4740200, 'Waskom', 'Waskom', '', '32.4787600', '-94.0596300', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'TX', '203', '', '', 2177, 87, 89, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe6100000010100000012f758fad08357c00551f701483d4040, NULL),
(4344697, 'Vivian', 'Vivian', '', '32.8715300', '-93.9874000', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'LA', '017', '', '', 3626, 78, 81, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe610000001010000008104c58f317f57c0cfbd874b8e6f4040, NULL),
(4326533, 'Greenwood', 'Greenwood', '', '32.4429300', '-93.9729600', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'LA', '017', '', '', 3191, 75, 81, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe610000001010000003c1405fa447e57c0693524eeb1384040, NULL),
(4330416, 'Lakeview', 'Lakeview', 'Lake View,Lakeview', '32.5232100', '-93.8293500', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'LA', '017', '', '', 948, 56, 64, 'America/Chicago', '2011-05-14', 0xe6100000010100000002bc0512147557c05778978bf8424040, NULL),
(4333758, 'Mooringsport', 'Mooringsport', 'Moorings Port,Mooringsport', '32.6876500', '-93.9610200', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'LA', '017', '', '', 786, 69, 74, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe6100000010100000053b3075a817d57c0158c4aea04584040, NULL),
(4317639, 'Bossier City', 'Bossier City', 'Bossier,Bossier City,Bozher Siti,bo xi er cheng,bosyeositi,bwsyr syty,bwwzhr  lwyyzyana,Божер Сити,بوسير سيتي,بوسیئر سٹی، لوزیانا,بووژر، لوئیزیانا,波西尔城,보셔시티', '32.5159900', '-93.7321200', 'P', 'PPL', 'US', '', 'LA', '015', '', '', 68094, 53, 53, 'America/Chicago', '2017-03-09', 0xe61000000101000000d72fd80ddb6e57c01288d7f50b424040, NULL);
COMMIT;


DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `nearest_city_temp`(IN `lat` TEXT, IN `lon` TEXT)
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
  SET @geopoint = CONCAT( "POINT(",@lat," ",@lon,")");
  SET @user_location = ST_GeomFromText( @geopoint, 4326);
  SELECT name,
         admin1,
         country,
         ST_Distance_Sphere(`position`, @user_location) / 1000 * 0.62 AS `distance`
    FROM `temp`
    WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere( `position`, @user_location) / 1000 * 0.62 < 50
    ORDER BY distance ASC
    LIMIT 1;
END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: My guess is it's related to the way PHP executes your `SET ... ; SET ... ; CALL ...;` statement when pasted into PHPMyAdmin's web interface. That statement is actually three different statement concatenated together, and I recall (from the many years ago that I spent time with PHP) that there is some weirdness about executing multiple statements like this. It may be that PHPMyAdmin simply is not expecting to return any results from a `CALL` statement, so it doesn't...

Comment: Can't say for sure but try removing ' ' from SET variables.

Comment: The "set...set...call" is how phpMyAdmin executes a routine from the "execute" link. I get the same behavior if I just put "call nearest_city_temp(32.63768889, -93.98388889);" in the phpMyAdmin SQL window and hit "Go".